# Auto Layout unable to satisfy constraints when adding more than 4 subviews

Tags: ios, autolayout

Auto Layout is doing something that doesn't make sense to me, but hopefully to one of you:

I have a UIView containerView and 5 UIViews coverview1-coverview5.
I want to place those 5 coverviews next to each other in containerView: same width, same bottom-alignment, no spacing anywhere, like |[ __ ][ __ ][ __ ][ __ ][ __ ]|

So I'm doing:

```
[coverviewContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: 
  @"H:|[coverview1(>=0)][coverview2(==coverview1)][coverview3(==coverview1)][coverview4(==coverview1)][coverview5(==coverview1)]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
```

and I get:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
(
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d5ae4f0 ItemView:0x1d58f6f0.centerX == ItemView:0x1d580410.centerX>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d5ae470 ItemView:0x1d58f6f0.centerX == ItemView:0x1d59b480.centerX>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d5aed70 ItemView:0x1d580410.centerX == ItemView:0x1d59b480.centerX>"
)
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d5ae470 ItemView:0x1d58f6f0.centerX == ItemView:0x1d59b480.centerX>
```

The strange thing is, I don't get the warning if I do any of the following:

```
[coverviewContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: 
  @"H:|[coverview1(>=0)]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
//or 
[coverviewContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: 
  @"H:|[coverview1(>=0)][coverview2(==coverview1)]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
//or
[coverviewContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: 
  @"H:|[coverview1(>=0)][coverview2(==coverview1)][coverview3(==coverview1)]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
//or
[coverviewContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: 
  @"H:|[coverview1(>=0)][coverview2(==coverview1)][coverview3(==coverview1)][coverview4(==coverview1)]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
//or
[coverviewContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: 
  @"H:|[coverview1(>=0)][coverview2(==coverview1)][coverview3(==coverview1)][coverview5(==coverview1)]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
```

(the last two are not the same, as I replaced coverview4 with coverview5)

Why can I only add up to 4 views? 
Why does adding a 5th one result in a sudden problem with the views centerX alignment?

Answer (score 2):

There's a great hint in the error message:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

So, studying the constraints show in the error:

```
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d5ae4f0 ItemView:0x1d58f6f0.centerX == ItemView:0x1d580410.centerX>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d5ae470 ItemView:0x1d58f6f0.centerX == ItemView:0x1d59b480.centerX>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d5aed70 ItemView:0x1d580410.centerX == ItemView:0x1d59b480.centerX>"
```

We can see that there's two constraints that specify the same thing on `ItemView` instance `0x1d58f6f0`. The first one says that it's `centerX` should be the same as `ItemView` instance `0x1d580410` `centerX`.

The second says that it's `centerX` should be the same as `ItemView` instance `0x1d59b480` `centerX`.

So, we have two constraints that contradict each other. They both try to tell that `ItemView` where to put it's horizontal center, and they both give different instructions. Think of two people shouting at you at the same time telling you to stand in two different places.

The Auto Layout runtime does it's best to handle this. Two conflicting constraints? Ignore one of them. In this case it ignores or "breaks" constraint `0x1d5ae470`.

What about your other constraints that work? Why does they work with four views and not five? We have to consider that the Auto Layout runtime will attempt to lay out the views in the *container view* according to your wishes. With four views, it can do what you want. With five views, it *tries* to do what you want, and fails. This depends on the constraints that are set up. If the views have to be aligned consecutively horizontally, can that be done given the size of the container view? If not, you'll need horizontal width constraints that allow the `ItemView` width to be reduced so that five can fit together nicely.

Another thing to think about is whether you have created these views `coverview1` through `coverview5` programmatically, or if they are set up within the Xib. Both have issues. If you added them programmatically, you need to set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` flag to `NO` to prevent Autoresizing constraints being added by default and doubtless conflict with the constraints you've set.

Alternatively, if you created these views in the Xib, you'll need to programmatically remove any existing constraints Interface Builder has forced upon you. Otherwise, again these could be conflicting with those you have added programmatically using the visual format language.